# Android studio doesn't let me use design mode

Tags: android, mobile

I recently downloaded Android studio and I can't access design view. I get this error:

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:159)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:164)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And when I try updating it says it is the most up to date version.
Thanks

Comment: change the api level from the dropdown menu. use a lower api device or download

Comment: Thanks It didn't come with other API but then I downloaded the older API and problem solved.

Comment: I updated the answer , if this helped you could you accept and upvote the same.

Comment: "the most up to date version" doesn't mean anything for us. You could be in the Stable channel, the Beta channel, or the Canary channel.  And you could also be using a different OS than we are. Please tell us the version number exactly.

Answer (score 0):

change the api level from the dropdown menu in the design view. use a lower api device or download from android sdk